Android requestFocus() on TextInputLayout + TextInputEditText focuses on button instead of text
I have a basic login screen for my application with two fields for a username (email) and password:

I'm trying to add functionality to automatically select the password field when the "next" button is clicked or when enter is pressed as follows, in the corresponding Activity class:
binding.usernameInputEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(
    (v, actionId, event) -> {
        if ((event == null && actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)
            || (event != null && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT))
        {
            binding.usernameInputEditText.clearFocus();
            binding.passwordInputEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            binding.passwordInputEditText.requestFocus();
        }
    }
);

The two fields in the Activity's corresponding layout XML:
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/usernameInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:hint="@string/usernameInputLayout_hint"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/usernameInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/passwordInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                android:hint="@string/passwordInputLayout_hint"
                app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernameInputLayout">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordInputEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

This appears to work just as expected most of the time, but sometimes (seemingly when the text in the email field reaches a certain length, hitting enter/return selects the password visibility toggle instead of the password field itself:


I've looked around online and tried several different fixes, including messing with setNextFocus**Id() and focusSearch(), removing the android:inputType field from the text fields, and calling requestFocus() twice. All still resulted in the same behavior. Is there some way to force requestFocus() to always select the text field itself (or another way of focusing on the text field)?
